# Looking to remove 'None' from all rows of Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dataframe, list-comprehension

Hi it looks like people are getting confused so I've removed my attempts and left just the highly pertinent parts of the question:

Code to create dataframe:

```
Sample = [{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'Jan': 150, 'Feb': 200, 'Mar': [.332, .326, .329]},
     {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 200, 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': [[.234, .246], None]},
     {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': [[.23], [.745, .398, .923], None] }]
df = pd.DataFrame(Sample)
```

Dataframe visualized:

```
df:
  account        Jan      Feb          Mar
Jones LLC  |     150   |   200    | [.332, .326, .329]
Alpha Co   |     200   |   210    | [[.234, .246], None]
Blue Inc   |     50    |   90     | [[.23], [.745, .398, .923], None]
```

**I need a function that can be applied to df to remove the 'None' values from df['Mar'], with the goal of returning this:**

```
df:
  account        Jan      Feb          Mar
Jones LLC  |     150   |   200    | [.332, .326, .329]
Alpha Co   |     200   |   210    | [.234, .246]
Blue Inc   |     50    |   90     | [.23], [.745, .398, .923]
```

Comment: What happens to `list_new` at the end of `nonefunction`?

Comment: not sure if this will help, but you can do list comprehension inside of a list comprehension. like `[[ y for y in x if something] for x in df['applicableColumn'] if something_else]` if you want to do something to each item of each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest list comprehensions:

`df['Mar'] = [[x for x in inner_list if x is not None] for inner_list in df['Mar']]`

You can also use `filter` to filter out `None` values

`df['Mar'] = [list(filter(lambda x: x is None, inner_list)) for inner_list in df['Mar']]`

Comment: But how would this work for a dataframe? Like this:  [[x for x in df['Column'] if x is not None] for df['Column'] in df] ?

Comment: I've never worked with pandas, but I think you'd replace `inner_list` with `df['Column']` and `outer_list` with `df`

Comment: Using my given example, that would be 

    [[x for x in df['Mar'] if x is not None] for df['Mar'] in df]

that returns:

[Feb, Feb, Feb],
[Jan, Jan, Jan],
[Mar, Mar, Mar],
[Account, Account, Account]

Comment: try `[[x for x in df[inner_key] if x is not None] for inner_key in df]`

Comment: Thats what I did: 
[[x for x in df['Mar'] if x is not None] for df['Mar'] in df]
it returned just Feb Feb Feb
                       Jan  Jan  Jan etc

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted how your data was structured. I tested this one: `[[x for x in inner_list if x is not None] for inner_list in df['Mar']]`, it returns `[[0.332, 0.326, 0.329], [[0.234, 0.246]], [[0.23], [0.745, 0.398, 0.923]]]`

Comment: Ahh nice! The problem is now the values are separate from the dataframe and not easily returned to their perspective rows

Comment: I think I figured it out:

df['New'] = [[[x for x in inner_list if x is not None]] for inner_list in df['Mar']]

If you edit your initial answer I'll approve it :) Thanks!!!!

Comment: edited! sorry about the confusion, the example was helpful though :)

Answer (score 1):

@user3080953 pretty much solved this, but I wanted to put a complete answer for posterity's sake:

```
df['New'] = [[[x for x in inner_list if x is not None]] for inner_list in df['Mar']]
```

This creates a new column that is "None"-free. I can then delete df['Mar']

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `mylist1` is a numpy array, you can do

```
mylist1[mylist1 != None]
```

to get the values you desire. But if you have multiple arrays or lists that you would like to slice at the same indices, you can adapt `enumerate` with the algorithm above and output each list or array at the desired indices.

Comment: This applies to a list, the question is how to apply a similar function to every row from df['Mar']
:(

Comment: You can convert the list to an array ... and you can apply the answer to your problem..

Comment: But my problem is with a dataframe, not a list? I edited the question so that it is really easily replicated. I'm looking to apply this to a dataframe with many thousands of rows, so I need a function that loops over each row